# SSIS Error "A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression."

Tags: ssis, expression

I have to present my RowCount as a zero filled string. My variables are
RecordCount data type integer and StringRecordCount data type String. My Expression Task is

@[User::StringRecordCount] =
@[User::RecordCount] < 10      ? "00000" + (DT_STR,1,1252) @[User::RecordCount] : 
@[User::RecordCount] < 100     ? "0000"  + (DT_STR,2,1252) @[User::RecordCount] :
@[User::RecordCount] < 1000    ? "000"   + (DT_STR,3,1252) @[User::RecordCount] :
@[User::RecordCount] < 10000   ? "00"    + (DT_STR,4,1252) @[User::RecordCount] :
@[User::RecordCount] < 100000  ? "0"     + (DT_STR,5,1252) @[User::RecordCount] :
(DT_STR,6,1252) @[User::RecordCount]

The Expression Task likes it but when I try to run the package I get the error "A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression."

I don't know why. Can somebody help?

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: how about if you prefix your @[User::RecordCount] variable with "00000" and then take the rightmost 5 or 6 characters of the string?  @[User::StringRecordCount] = right("00000" + @[User::RecordCount],6)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. I used the same code (with the exception of the @[User::StringRecordCount]), put it into a Derived Column and wrapped the whole thing in a (DT_STR,6,1252). Worked perfectly.

Thanks,

Dick